# Python beginner recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to get a simple function which takes n and prints

```
If n > 0:
    print((n*'*')+(n*'!'), end=' ')
```

and trying to get the same solution but recursively. I am a beginner to recursion, and often I get the "higher level of thinking", but I am having trouble understanding the code that must follow.

My base case is that when n is 0 it prints nothing. When n is more than 1 it will print n copies of * + n copies of!

```
def repeat(n):
    if n <= 0:
        pass
    else:
        repeat(n-1)
        print((n*'*')+(n*'!'), end=' ')
```

right now it prints n, and then n-1 successively until 0. I have tried breaking it up into two print statements and using more than one recursion .. but it becomes a messy pattern.

I am also not allowed to use loops. This one is driving me insane; I have come up with several solutions to it besides the easy one line statement, but none that use recursion.

Comment: Hint: you have an `if n <= 0` clause, but you don't use it.  BTW, lose the "`n*'*'`".

Comment: Another hint: http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#index-23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simpler if you build and return a string and print it outside of the function, like this:

```
def printPattern(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return ''
    return '*' + printPattern(n-1) + '!'
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
def printPattern(n):
    return '*' + printPattern(n-1) + '!' if n > 0 else ''
```

Either way, this works:

```
print printPattern(5)
> *****!!!!!
```

Comment: I think, OP doesn't want this. He said, when n is more than 1, then print `n copies of *` + `n copies of !`.

Comment: So, for `n = 5` :- `5 *` and `5 !`, then `n = 4` : - `4 *` and `4!`, and so on, till `n = 0`.

Comment: Or did I misunderstood the question? :(

Comment: @RohitJain I believe my answer is correct, "n copies of *" plus "n copies of !" means just that, say for n==3: ***!!!

Comment: Thank you Oscar!  That was it, I was using that technique but not in an iteration before!  This was it. Thank you!

Comment: @jwl4 you're welcome! if this answer was the most helpful for you, please don't forget to accept it by clicking on the check mark to its left

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a solution for `n - 1`. Prepend `*` and append `!`.

```
def repeat(n):
    if n > 0:
        print("*", end=" ")
        repeat(n - 1)
        print("!", end=" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

The following does what you appear to want.

```
def repeat(n):
  def stars(n):
    return '*'+stars(n-1)+'!' if n > 0 else ''
  print stars(n)
```

For example, `repeat(5)` prints `*****!!!!!` and `repeat(8)` prints
`********!!!!!!!!`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually know what you're asking... If there's a more efficient or better way of doing this? This would be quite obvious:

```
def repeat(n):
    if n >= 0:
        print((n*'*')+(n*'!'), end=' ')
        return repeat(n-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use two strings here, and return a concatenated string of those two strings when `n<=0` and use `return` instead of printing inside function:

```
def repeat(n, strs1="", strs2=""):     # The Default value of strings is ""

    if n <= 0:
        return strs1 + strs2   # if n<=0 then concatenate the two strings and return them
    else:
        strs1 += "*"          # Add * to strs1
        strs2 += "!"          # Add ! to strs2
        return repeat(n-1, strs1, strs2)  # Pass n-1, as well as the two strings to a recursive call

print(repeat(5))
print(repeat(3))
```

**Output:**

```
*****!!!!!
***!!!
```